# Parse LocalDate json to moment in Angular

Tags: json, angular, momentjs, localdate

I'm receiving LocalDate from backend in JSON witch looks like

```
{"dayOfMonth":25,
 "dayOfWeek":"TUESDAY",
 "dayOfYear":206,
 "month":"JULY",
 "monthValue":7,
 "year":2017,
 "hour":0,
 "minute":0,
 "nano":0,
 "second":0,
 "chronology":{"id":"ISO","calendarType":"iso8601"}}}
```

and I want to parse it to a moment js object

```
 moment(this.car.overview).format();
```

> Invalid date

```
console.log(moment().format(car.overview));
```

> ERROR TypeError: format.replace is not a function

Anyone knows how to get a valid moment object from this JSON ?

Comment: try something like moment().year(car.year).month(car.month)..... and see where that gets you. please note that there might be some inconsistencies like is January the 0th month or the 1st

Comment: this date is one property on car entity and i would like to get it as a one valid moment object

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You mean this?

PS: If you receive a JSON string you need to JSON.parse it first

```js
var overview = {
  "dayOfMonth": 25,
  "dayOfWeek": "TUESDAY",
  "dayOfYear": 206,
  "month": "JULY",
  "monthValue": 7,
  "year": 2017,
  "hour": 0,
  "minute": 0,
  "nano": 0,
  "second": 0,
  "chronology": {
    "id": "ISO",
    "calendarType": "iso8601"
  }
}

console.log(
  moment({
    y: overview.year,
    M: overview.monthValue - 1,
    d: overview.dayOfMonth,
    h: overview.hour,
    m: overview.minute,
    s: overview.second,
    ms: overview.nano
  })
)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.18.1/moment.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: do you know a way to automatically parse json to moment Object ??

Comment: i mean a get String and as a output i get moment object ??

Comment: Yes, I just posted it. Moment may allow custom formats but it does not pick and choose stuff from an object you have. If you have a string you may need to JSON.parse it first

Answer (score 0):

what you need to do is

```
 moment().minute(this.car.minute.overview.minute).second(this.car.minute.overview.second).hours(this.car.minute.overview.hour)
```

and so on for information read https://momentjs.com/docs/#/get-set/

Comment: car.overview this property is a string "{"dayOfMonth":25,"dayOfWeek":"TUESDAY","dayOfYear":206,"month":"JULY","monthValue":7,"year":2017,"hour":0,"minute":0,"nano":0,"second":0,"chronology":{"id":"ISO","calendarType":"iso8601"}}}"

Comment: let something = JSON.parse(car.overview); and then use 'something' variable. instead of this.car.minute.overview

Comment: And i would like to parse this String to Valid moment object

Comment: i told you how to do it 1 parse to object. then use answer

Comment: let something = JSON.parse(car.overview); and then use 'something' variable. instead of this.car.minute.overview gives me an error "ERROR SyntaxError: Unexpected token o in JSON at position 1"

Comment: let something = JSON.parse(this.car.overview)
 moment().minute(something.minute).second(something.second).hours(something.hour)